# Selecionar apenas primeiro lugar do primeiro semestre - Código SQL Server

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, ssms

Fiz este código para o SQL Server para selecionar quantas vezes o piloto "AsdoVolante" ficou em primeiro lugar no primeiro semestre de 2017. Porém o mesmo não funciona. O que poderá estar mal?

```
SELECT P.Data, Nm.Nome, epp.PosicaoFinal
FROM Prova P, Piloto Nm, EquipaParticipaProva epp
WHERE epp.PosicaoFinal = (SELECT PosicaoFinal FROM EquipaParticipaProva where PosicaoFinal = 1)
HAVING Nm.Nome ='AsdoVolante' AND P.Data BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-06-30';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode obter tais informações realizando o vínculo das informações com `JOIN` e restringindo no `WHERE`:

```
SELECT Nm.Nome,
       COUNT(epp.PosicaoFinal) AS quantidade
  FROM Prova P
       INNER JOIN EquipaParticipaProva epp ON epp.IdProva = P.IdProva
       INNER JOIN Piloto Nm ON epp.IdPiloto = epp.IdPiloto
 WHERE epp.PosicaoFinal = 1
   and Nm.Nome = 'AsdoVolante'
   and P.Data BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-06-30';
 GROUP BY Nm.Nome
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT P.Data, Nm.Nome, epp.PosicaoFinal
FROM Prova P, Piloto Nm, EquipaParticipaProva epp
WHERE epp.PosicaoFinal = (SELECT epp.PosicaoFinal FROM EquipaParticipaProva where epp.PosicaoFinal = 1)
HAVING Nm.Nome ='AsdoVolante' AND P.Data BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-06-30';
```

Comment: @EliasVentura Obrigado pela sua resposta mas o código não funciona :(

Comment: @TiagoS O codigo do Elias não funcionava

Answer (score 0):

Tem que primeiro verificar qual erro está exibindo.

De toda forma, tente o select abaixo:
        SELECT P.Data, Nm.Nome, epp.PosicaoFinal
        FROM Prova P, Piloto Nm, EquipaParticipaProva epp
        WHERE epp.PosicaoFinal = 1
        AND Nm.Nome ='AsdoVolante' AND P.Data BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-06-30';